# How to name a repeated pattern sequence inside Plus?

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation

Here is a sample expression that contains a bunch of `f` and some other stuff:

```
expr = a f[x] + b f[y] + 2 c f[z] + f[a] + Cos[y] + 3 f[y] + Sqrt[x]
```

and I would like to apply function `modify1` to the part of the expression containing `f[x]` `f[y]` and `f[z]` exclusively (not `f[a]`), and `modify2` to the rest.  The pattern that matches is:  `Plus[rest___, Times[_., f[x | y | z]] ..]` and I am using it like so:

```
expr /. Plus[rest___, Times[_., f[x | y | z]] ..] :> modify1[Plus[(*???*)]] + modify2[Plus[rest]]
```

> ```
> modify1[] + modify2[Sqrt[x] + Cos[y] + f[a]]
> ```

What I want is:

> ```
> modify1[a f[x] + b f[y] + 2 c f[z] + 3 f[y]] + modify2[Sqrt[x] + Cos[y] + f[a]]
> ```

To make this work, I need to name the part of the pattern that has all the `f[x]`, `f[y]`, `f[z]` so I can apply the `modify1` function to it.  But if I try to insert a name to the pattern like so:

```
expr /. Plus[rest___, (name: Times[_., f[x | y | z]] ..)] :> modify1[Plus[name]] + modify2[Plus[rest]]
```

The pattern matches incorrectly:

> ```
> modify1[a f[x]] + modify2[Sqrt[x] + Cos[y] + f[a] + 3 f[y] + b f[y] + 2 c f[z]]
> ```

How do I name `Times[_., f[x | y | z]] ..` inside of `Plus` so that the pattern correctly matches and can be subsequently manipulated?  Note that the list of arguments `x` `y` `z` is variable, so I prefer to avoid a brute force solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
modify1[Plus @@ #] + modify2[Plus @@ Complement[List @@ expr, #]] &[Cases[expr, _Times]]
```

> modify1[a f[x] + 3 f[y] + b f[y] + 2 c f[z]] + modify2[Sqrt[x] +
>   Cos[y] + f[a]]

What should happen to a "single" `f[x|y|z]` not being part of `Times`?

Depending on what you want you could modify the argument like

```
Cases[expr, Times[__, f[x | y | z]] | f[x | y | z]]
```

Comment: This is great.  It seems like `Cases[expr, _. f[a|b|c]]` works, too.  Any reason you can think of why it wouldn't work?

Comment: The default level specification for `Cases` is 1. You may have to use `Infinity` or something higher.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is slightly modified to include the cases where `f[x]` may not have a multiplier and `f[a]` may have a multiplier or be enclosed in a function.

```
expr = a f[x] + b f[y] + 2 c f[z] + f[a] +
             Cos[y] + f[y] + Sqrt[x] + Cos[f[a]]
```

It is desired to capture all elements that include `f[a]` or `f[b]`.

```
Cases[expr, f[a | b] | (x_ /; MemberQ[x, f[a | b]])]
(* {Cos[f[a]], f[a]} *)
```

This will be used as input to `Eldo's` fine answer where the expression is converted to a list and the `Complement` is taken. However since this returns the elements containing `f[a]` the output will be applied to `modify2` and the `Complement` to `modify1`.

```
modify1[Plus @@ Complement[List @@ expr, #]] +
   modify2[Plus @@ #] &[Cases[expr, f[a | b] | (x_ /; MemberQ[x, f[a | b]])]]
```

returns

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice.  In a comment to Eldo, I mentioned using `Cases[expr, _. f[a|b|c]]` to capture the possibility `f` doesn't have a multiplier.  What do you think?

Comment: That handles multipliers on `f[a]` fine. It doesn't handle the case where `f[a]` is an argument to a function. If your data only uses multipliers `Cases[expr, _. f[a|b|c]]` should work fine.